# BeaconTransmitting Eddystone TLM frame AltBeacon no work

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I'm try to create complete eddystone Beacon emulator. No problem with URL, UID frames.
But when i try to emitting TLM extra data, no work.

BeaconParser extraparser, is included when the advertising start?

This is my code:

```
    //create BeaconParse Like UID and add extraparser for TLM
     BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser();
                beaconParser.addExtraDataParser(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));
                beaconParser.setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT);

                BeaconTransmitter mBeaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(this, beaconParser);
//this is the beacon with info for UID and ExtraData with 5 values of TLM
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                        .setId1("0x2F234454F4911BA9FFA6")//UID
                        .setId2("0x0BDB87539B67") //UID
                        .setManufacturer(0xfeaa)   //0x00​E0 eddystone
                        .setBeaconTypeCode(0x00) //0X00 withTLM  
                        .setMultiFrameBeacon(true) //TLM
                        .setServiceUuid(0xfeaa) //TLM
                        .setTxPower(-65) //UID
                        .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l}))//?
                        .setExtraDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0L, 3580L,5776L, 289780991L, 28978000L}))//TLM extradata
                        .build();

//then create the Transmitter and start it
  BeaconTransmitter bt = new BeaconTransmitter(this, beaconParser);
 bt.startAdvertising(beacon);
```

The problem is when I detect the Beacon, it comes with MExtraDataFields =null;

I think the TLM info are not included in advertisingData emitting by BeaconTransmitter.

Is TLM beacontramitting supported? Is a BeaconTransmitter limitation or the problem is beacon i careate?

Maybe i need to use the Identifier for send this kind of info.

I try with, Samsung S5 and Samsung s7Edge, and using 2.9.1 version of AltBeacon

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that won't work.  The `BeaconTransmitter` class does not automatically emit Eddystone-TLM based on extra data fields.  Although I have never explicitly tested it, I don't think it can be used to transmit that frame at all, because it is impossible to construct a `Beacon` object instance with only data fields, as would be necessary to transmit Eddystone-TLM with the existing `BeaconTransmitter` class.

That said, this is a reasonable feature request, and I'd certainly welcome a pull request if you'd like to work on adding support for this.

Full Disclosure:  I am the lead developer on the Android Beacon Library open source project.

Answer (score 0):

Oks, thanks a lot for your quick response.

Yesterday donwload your code, from master and Eddystone Eid, for analize if the problem that the BEaconEmmitter don't advertise the ExtraData.

After read some doc in your web, i understand that TLM info are in another advertising package that match with other EddyStone/Ibeacon by method:

```
  private String getBeaconKey(Beacon beacon) {
    if (matchBeaconsByServiceUUID) {
        return beacon.getBluetoothAddress() + beacon.getServiceUuid();
    } else {
        return beacon.getBluetoothAddress();
    }
}
```

And if match, add extraData to the beacon.

For that i'm modify BeaconTransmitter startAdvertising method, for try to send the advertisingdata of tlm, with the same beaconTransmitter(because need to have the same bTMac in the UID Beacon and in TLM Beacon), something like this:

```
 if (mBeacon.isMultiFrameBeacon()) {
            byte[] advertisingExtraDataBytes = mBeaconParser.getBeaconAdvertisementDataFromTLM(mBeacon);
            //segun https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/eddystone-tlm/tlm-plain.md 14 bytes
            //solo con esa info cmo matchea? typebeacon 0x20
            try {
                AdvertiseData.Builder dataBuilder = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
                //always bigger than 0
                if (serviceUuid > 0) {
                    byte[] serviceUuidBytes = new byte[]{
                            (byte) (serviceUuid & 0xff),
                            (byte) ((serviceUuid >> 8) & 0xff)};
                    ParcelUuid parcelUuid = parseUuidFrom(serviceUuidBytes);
                    dataBuilder.addServiceData(parcelUuid, advertisingExtraDataBytes);
                    dataBuilder.addServiceUuid(parcelUuid);
                  //  dataBuilder.setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false); //no in tlm
                //    dataBuilder.setIncludeDeviceName(false);//no in tlm

                } else {
                    dataBuilder.addManufacturerData(manufacturerCode, advertisingExtraDataBytes);// in tlm?
                }

                AdvertiseSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder();

                settingsBuilder.setAdvertiseMode(mAdvertiseMode); //need?
                settingsBuilder.setTxPowerLevel(mAdvertiseTxPowerLevel);//need?
                settingsBuilder.setConnectable(false);

                mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settingsBuilder.build(), dataBuilder.build(), getAdvertiseCallback());
                LogManager.d(TAG, "Started advertisement with callback: %s", getAdvertiseCallback());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogManager.e(e, TAG, "Cannot start advertising due to exception");
            }

        }
```

Still no working, but I don't know yet if AltBeacon already support this or not, and no spend more time with it.

I work now with this code, for get the correct format of the byte array, all your comments are welcome. If it works fine, talk about pull request, beause i don't know if put the code inside BeaconTransmitter is the best way to implements this kind of extraData Frame.

I have another ideas for improve the AltBeacon, for battery consume and background scanner, we will talk about that too.

Thanks again David, you and your collaborators are doing awesome work with Altbeacon, so if I can help with this feature, it has.

Comment: hey! @davidgyoung  I don't have time yet for develop that, but i can search info about how  info in advertising data for TLM:
eddystone Preamble data advertising package
0x02,0x01,0x06,0x03,0x03,0xAA,0xFE,0x11,0x16,0xAA,0xFE
plus Tlm service data

Comment: 0x32,0x00(version)...
But the important thing is that the interleaving of the TLMframe is beaconreader responsability, and this match the TLM frame with URL/UID  , by Bluetooth Address. The BeaconTransmitter or the bluetooh Scanner LE assing diferents btAddress each time.

Answer (score 0):

@Davidgyoung, promises are debt ^_^ Sorry, for the waiting, finally, I have found time to retake the problem of transmitting TLM Frame.

This is the complete code for transmitting TLM frame(without AltBeacon), but you need BeaconTransmitter for create UID or URL Eddystone Frame, for check it.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
  private void createEddyStone_TLM2() { 

    final int len = 12;
    final byte TLM_FRAME = 0x20;
    byte[] ServiceData = new byte[2 + len];

    ServiceData[0] = TLM_FRAME;
    ServiceData[1] = 0;
    ParcelUuid parcelUuid = parcelUuidFromShortUUID(0xFEAA);
    final int pos = 0;//4 TLM
    byte[] frameData = generateTLMFrameData();
    System.arraycopy(frameData, pos, ServiceData, 2, len);

    AdvertiseData advertiseData = new AdvertiseData.Builder().setIncludeDeviceName(false)
        .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
        .addServiceData(parcelUuid, ServiceData)
        .addServiceUuid(parcelUuid)
        .build();

    AdvertiseSettings advertiseSettings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder().setAdvertiseMode(1)
        .setTxPowerLevel(2)
        .setConnectable(false)
        .build();

    try {

      BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
          (BluetoothManager) this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
      if (bluetoothManager != null) {
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        BluetoothLeAdvertiser bleAdvertiser = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
        bleAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(getAdvertiseCallback());
        bleAdvertiser.startAdvertising(advertiseSettings, advertiseData, null,
            getAdvertiseCallback());
      }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
      Log.e("", "error", e);
    }
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) private AdvertiseCallback getAdvertiseCallback() {
    AdvertiseCallback advertiseCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
      @Override public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        Log.e("","Something wrong with Advertising");
      }
      @Override public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        Log.i("","Advertising start succesfully");
      }
    };
    return advertiseCallback;
  }
  public static ParcelUuid parcelUuidFromShortUUID(long serviceId) {
    long leastSigBits = 0x800000805f9b34fbL;
    return new ParcelUuid(new UUID(0x1000 | (serviceId << 32),leastSigBits));
  }

  private byte[] generateTLMFrameData() {
    byte[] data = new byte[12];

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    buffer.putShort((short) getTLMBattery());
    int temperature = getTLMTemperature();
    buffer.putShort((short) (temperature << 8));
    buffer.putInt((int) getTLMPduCount());
    buffer.putInt((int) getTLMPowerOnTime() / 100);

    return data;
  }

  private int getTLMTemperature() {
    //todo make random, now 10º
    return 266;
  }

  private int getTLMBattery() {
    //todo make random
    return 1234;
  }

  private int getTLMPduCount() {
    //todo make random
    return 0;
  }

  private long getTLMPowerOnTime() {
    //todo - createtime, but don't care
    return SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
  }
```

I do this way inside my :app, i can add this in AltBeacon if you want.

regards, Alberto